# How to render a control to look like ComboBox with Visual Styles enabled?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a control that is modelled on a **ComboBox**. I want to render the control so that the control **border** looks like that of a standard **Windows ComboBox**. Specifically, I have followed the MSDN documentation and all the rendering of the control is correct except for rendering when the control is disabled.

Just to be clear, this is for a system with **Visual Styles** enabled.  Also, all parts of the control render properly except the border around a disabled control, which does not match the disabled **ComboBox border** colour.

I am using the **VisualStyleRenderer** class. MSDN suggests using the `VisualStyleElement.TextBox` element for the **TextBox** part of the **ComboBox** control but a standard disabled **TextBox** and a standard disabled **ComboBox** draw slightly differently (one has a light grey border, the other a light blue border).

How can I get correct rendering of the control in a disabled state?

Answer (score 11):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for but you should check out the **VisualStyleRenderer** in the System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles-namespace.

1. [VisualStyleRenderer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer.aspx) (MSDN)
2. [How to: Render a Visual Style Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171735.aspx) (MSDN)
3. [VisualStyleElement.ComboBox.DropDownButton.Disabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.combobox.dropdownbutton.disabled.aspx) (MSDN)

Since VisualStyleRenderer won't work if the user don't have visual styles enabled (he/she might be running 'classic mode' or an operative system prior to Windows XP) you should always have a fallback to the ControlPaint class.

```
// Create the renderer.
if (VisualStyleInformation.IsSupportedByOS 
    && VisualStyleInformation.IsEnabledByUser) 
{
    renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(
        VisualStyleElement.ComboBox.DropDownButton.Disabled);
}
```

and then do like this when drawing:

```
if(renderer != null)
{
    // Use visual style renderer.
}
else
{
    // Use ControlPaint renderer.
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is great info but I find it giving me the same results as something like `ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(e.Graphics, arrowRectangle, arrowState);` which is the old style or DrowDownList style somewhat (background of arrow is gray instead transparent)?  I was hoping to be able to get the same style as a default ComboBox in VS2019 (transparent with gray arrow pointing down and when hover, lite blue background).

Answer (score 1):

Are any of the [ControlPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint_members.aspx) methods useful for this?  That's what I usually use for custom-rendered controls.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13372/1039753) provided by [Patrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936/patrik-svensson) I was trying to use the [VisualStyleRenderer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer.aspx) as well but could not get exactly what I wanted.

I found out that you can use some undocumented class names instead.  The `VisualStyleRenderer()` constructor allows for a string class value.  If you are lucky enough to be able to find the one you are after (like I did below) then you can use styles other then the ones defined in the `VisualStyleElement` class.

```
_renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer("WindowsForms10::COMBOBOX", 1, 1);
```

### FULL EXAMPLE

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Process the base painting events
    base.OnPaint(e);

    // Check for visual support
    bool vStyleRender = false;
    if (VisualStyleInformation.IsSupportedByOS && VisualStyleInformation.IsEnabledByUser)
        vStyleRender = true;

    bool standardComboBoxRender = ComboBoxRenderer.IsSupported;

    if (!vStyleRender && !standardComboBoxRender)
    {
        this.Parent.Text = "Visual Styles Disabled";
        return;
    }
    this.Parent.Text = "CustomComboBox Enabled";

    // Always draw the main text box and drop down arrow in their current states
    if (vStyleRender)
    {
        // Use visual style renderer
        VisualStyleRenderer _renderer = null;

        // Draw the base text box
        _renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.TextBox.TextEdit.Normal);
        _renderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, topTextBoxRectangle);

        // Draw the arrow
        //_renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.ComboBox.DropDownButton.Normal);
        _renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer("WindowsForms10::COMBOBOX", 1, 1);
        _renderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, arrowRectangle);
    }
}
```