# How to render the edit portion of a ComboBox using OwnerDrawFixed with same color as a regular ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` that has `DrawMode` property set to `OwnerDrawFixed`. The rendering of the items is done in `DrawItem` event.

```
void OnDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
   e.DrawBackground();
}
```

The main issue is the color of the edit portion is white, which is different from other ComboBoxes (that use `DrawMode` = `Normal`).

[image: ![enter image description here]

Above: `Normal`. Below: `OwnerDrawFixed`

---

What I have tried is to use some `SystemColors` such as `Control` but it does not works (it render the dropdown in gray but not exactly the same one).

```
void OnDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.State == DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit)
   {
       e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Control, e.Bounds);
   }
}
```

I took a look at source code of the [ComboBox](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,e83c7b91eda8635a) and it does not seems to rely on C# code for rendering (seems rendering is done in Win32). Still, I am wondering which color it use (it there a way to replicate this in C# ?). This is for Win10. I have notified that Win11 render all dropdowns with white color.

Comment: Try [How to render a control to look like ComboBox with Visual Styles enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2874/719186)